# how to display menu on mouseover in symfony or php?

Tags: javascript

I want to display menu when cursor is on 'Home' option in symfony. I have created submenu using json but i am not able to display that menu. Please help me on this. Thanks in advance.

Comment: It might just be me, but the question is not very clear.  What is the 'Home' option?  Are you trying to display a menu when the mouse passes over a link?

Comment: sorry for being unclear ... yeah i want to display the menu when mouse passes over a link ... thanks ...

Answer (score 1):

You will have to do this in Javascript, not in PHP, and how you're doing it depends on whether you're using a JS library and in that case, which.

In jQuery you can do something like this:

```
$('#idOfHomeButton').mouseover(function(evt) {
  $('#idOfMenuDiv').show();
});

$('#idOfHomeButton').mouseout(function(evt) {
  $('#idOfMenuDiv').hide();
});
```

Comment: thanks a lot for your answer ... with this i can display the menu but i am not able to display it below its parent menu option ... can u pls help me on this?